# Remove all text after first occurence of character, including any characters preceding that don't have a space

Tags: jquery, regex

Given any sentence with a comma:

```
var myText = 'This is mine, all of it, and more!'
```

I'd like to remove everything after the first comma, including the word preceding it.

The above example would output:

```
This is
```

If there's no comma, everything should be returned.

I assume I'll need to use something along the lines of, but not sure where to go from here:

```
myText.replace(/.*,/, "");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
var str = "This is mine, all of it, and more!";
str = str.replace(/ *\b[^, ]+,.*/, "");
//=> This is
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vO7nW3/1)

Answer (score 0):

Well, **I** find regular expressions unreadable, so perhaps consider:

```
if (str.indexOf(',') != -1){
    /*
        parts = str.split(',')
        words = parts[0].split(' ')
        # remove last word and re-join
        return words.slice(0, -1).join(' ');
    */
    return str.split(',')[0].split(' ').slice(0,-1).join(' ');
}
return str;
```